# LDAP users in Catalina cannot log in - CRAM-MD5 error in opendirectoryd

Tags: macos, catalina, ldap, open-directory

I'm using Catalina 10.15.4 OSX as client and FreeBSD 12-1 with openldap-sasl-server-2.4.48_1 as Openldap server. I've configured the LDAP server using Direct Utility.

- I can see the LDAP users on Directory Editor tab;
- I can use "id user" in terminal showing the user, its groups etc;
- I can use "dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/user" that shows all user info;
- I can use "dscacheutil -q user -a name user" that shows all user info;
- I can change to root in terminal and then "su - user" and it works (I've created the home directory and mapped to #/Users/$uid$;
- BUT I CAN'T login using user.

All network users are enabled to login. I've tried using "ssh user@localhost" and at Login Window. It doesn't work.

Setting debug with "odutil set log debug" and taking a look in Console logs:

```
opendirectoryd  failed CRAM-MD5 authentication for authzid - '<private>' authcid - '<private>' error 49
opendirectoryd  ODRecordVerifyPassword failed with result ODErrorCredentialsInvalid
opendirectoryd  nw_path_evaluator_start [78C31F06-08D0-4EF9-B584-EB41028A814D IPv6#0d17d740.389 generic, local: IPv6#ef0057ec.49455, indefinite]
    path: unsatisfied (No network route)
```

On server, CRAM-MD5 is available.

```
supportedSASLMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
supportedSASLMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-256
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
```

What's going wrong? How to use LDAP users on OSX?

-

There are some tutorial on the Internet about editing a directory configuration file (plist). However, this had worked in later versions of OSX. For example:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string DIGEST-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/yourldapserver.plist 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string CRAM-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/yourldapserver.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string NTLM" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/yourldapserver.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string GSSAPI" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/yourldapserver.plist
```

In Catalina we can't edit anymore this file (yourldapserver.plist). I've tried to usa another tool, **defaults**, but the file can only be altered if we copy it to another place. At the normal system location we can't edit to test these configurations.

Answer (score 4):

Does it work for you if you try to edit the plist file indirectly with odutil, as follows:

```
odutil set configuration /LDAPv3/foo.example.com module ldap option "Denied SASL Methods" CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN NTLM
```

Comment: The OP never responded, but this worked for me. Thank you.